# how to create a custom contacts folder in the office 365 mailbox using API?

Tags: powershell, api, office365, exchangewebservices

how to create a custom contacts folder in the office 365 mailbox using API? I can't find any documentation for PowerShell or rest api.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the API information to create contacts folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633637(v=exchg.80)